# How to give print command from javascript so that it always sets the paper size to A4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I want to trigger print action of browser from javascript.

I know simple `window.print()` method will call a print dialog box with some print settings.

Is there anyway we can alter print settings from javascript code?
[image: I need to change settings of this dialog box through code.]

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336995/set-printing-preferences-from-js

Comment: http://htmloutput.risd.gd/project-winklerprins-printdotjayess/