# How can I set @page CSS attributes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, css

One can make a page be printed in landscape mode with

```
@page {size: landscape;}
```

But I only want a page to be printed in landscape when some conditions are met (e.g. when there is wide content on the page).

How can I set this attribute with jQuery / JavaScript?

### What doesn't work

```
$('@page')
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: @page
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery is trying to select some element named `page` and with invalid selector `@`.

All you need to do is add `@page{size: landscape;}` to CSS

```
$('head').append('<style>@page{size: landscape;}</style>')
```

Comment: Hm. This solution looks like a hack. But it works in Chrome 60 (Linux), but not in Firefox (seems to be a problem of the CSS, not of the JS solution you suggest)

Comment: Works for me even on Firefox, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the rule via the [`styleSheets` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) and change its size.

Here's an example: The CSS declares `@page { size: landscape; }` and then the code changes it to `portrait`:

```js
Array.from(document.styleSheets).forEach(ss => {
    Array.from(ss.rules || ss.cssRules).forEach(rule => {
      if (rule instanceof CSSPageRule) {
        rule.style.size = "portrait";
        console.log("New rule size: " + rule.style.size);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
@page { size: landscape; }
```

That example keeps going to find all `CSSPageRules`, but if you know there's only one you could use `some` instead:

```
Array.from(document.styleSheets).some(
    ss => Array.from(ss.rules || ss.cssRules).forEach(rule => {
      if (rule instanceof CSSPageRule) {
        rule.style.size = "portrait";
        console.log("New rule size: " + rule.style.size);
        return true;
      }
    })
);
```