# Change @Page Size on runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do have following CSS:

```
@page { 
    margin: 0; 
    size: 7.8cm;
}
```

I need to change the height of the print page on runtime, with javascript or jQuery. Does somebody know how to do that?

Comment: for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page      You may need to manually update the innerHTML of a <style> element containing the css code block you wrote using JS.

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath You can't change the `.innerHTML` of a `style` element and have the new rules kick in. Instead, you must use the **[CSSOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model)**

Answer (score 1):

Do this my friend, [as contributed by @Justinas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45995560/2200913):

```
$('head').append('<style>@page{margin: 0;size: 7.8cm;}</style>');
```

Comment: Do you know how you would do this if you had a CSP blocking inline style blocks like this?

Comment: @ChrisSpittles You can try to ask Bing AI Chatbot, it will give you some options to rectify this.