# Hardcoding printing preferences for web app

Tags: javascript, php, css, printing, settings

I have build an application for my employer which is required to track orders and print labels.

The label is basically a table element which appears in a child window, has the javascript 'print' function called, then closes the window.

The data prints, but it includes the header and footer from the web browser, goes to the the default printer which (at times) is incorrect etc.

I can set the printing preferences on my PC so that it prints correctly, but this will be rolled out to many users who won't know how to set their printing preferences.... is there a way I can hard code the preferences using JS, JQuery, CSS or PHP?
in particular, I need to set:

The printer used

Printing orientation

Page height

Page width

Disable header and footer

Thank you for any help you may offer :)

Comment: Simply put: you can't. The printer preferences is the OS responsibility. If you want to control that, then you should build a stand-alone application instead of a web application. A web application can't change anything on the users system. Which is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

[PrintJs](http://printjs.crabbly.com/) might help you upto some extend. But you cant set the printing preferences using JS. For security reason javascript don't allow to access/change the system configuration which makes sense.

[Visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336995/set-printing-preferences-from-js?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)