# How to print 1-3 images onto a single output page?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a code block in Squarespace that results in showing a photograph.  The photo is currently set at 2500px wide.  My goal is to have a print button that allows the user to print this image - but the most important thing is that I want it to print onto a single page.  Most likely my final code will require printing three images - again, onto a single page.  I'm not a programmer at all and have relied on tracking down the following code to works to isolate the image(s) and print them.  However, right now the images print onto 4-8 pages!  I need to find javascript or CSS code to make sure that the final print is restricted to a single page.  Can anyone modify my current code to do that?

I realize this question is similar to many other posted questions.  However, I've tried @media print CSS commands, but they don't seem to work at all (likely due to me not understanding the code!).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Printdiv</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function printyourimage(){

var print_div = document.getElementById("image1");
var print_area = window.open();
print_area.document.write(print_div.innerHTML);
print_area.document.close();
print_area.focus();
print_area.print();
print_area.close();

    }

  </script>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Print Image" onclick="printyourimage()">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

To recap: this function prints a single image onto multiple pages; however, I want to restrict the final print job to a single piece of paper.  If I change the code to accommodate two or three images, I still want this to code to direct the images to print onto a single piece of paper.

Comment: Unfortunately that would be something entirely controlled by the print driver/manager, which JS does not have access to. See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336995/set-printing-preferences-from-js)

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but in theory it should work. Determine the number of images being displayed `image_count`, then using a switch, determine the max height that the image should be displayed at in % (you might need to play with the sizes to accomplish the correct fit).

**based on comments:**

```
<style>
img{max-width:200px;margin:10px;display:block;}
</style>
```

**original answer:**

```
var image_count = 3;
var image_height = "85%";

switch(image_count){
   case 2: image_height = "45%";
   case 3: image_height = "30%";
}

var print_div = document.getElementById("image1");
var print_area = window.open();
print_area.document.write(`<html><head><style>img{max-height:${image_height};}</style></head><body>${print_div.innerHTML}</body></html>`);
print_area.document.close();
print_area.focus();
print_area.print();
print_area.close();
```