# How to change the dropdown value in Print dialogue box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

How to change the value of this dropdown using `Javascript/Jquery` ?
**Description** Iam having a frontend where the user will search and print the details. For print i had used reactToPrint package. after hitting the print button want to set default value in Save as PDF in destination dropdown.
[image: click to see Image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. It is expected that you have done sufficient research efford and at least tried to solve an issue yourself -> What have you tried so far?

Comment: @tacoshy Hi, im trying to set a default value "Save as PDF" for destination dropddown in this dialogue box when the user hits print button.

Comment: is that dropdown part of your website or part of the browsers setting?

Comment: That's a system level dialog box within the browser. You cannot amend it through Javascript. What you're attempting to do is not possible.

Comment: @tacoshy its a part of browser setting.

Comment: then you can't. As it is a browser setting it is controlled by the user not by the website. It would be a security issue if you could overwrite the users settings with a webpage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if that dropdown is part of the browser (system) settings, **You can not change the system level settings**.

I suggest you use a "Save as PDF" button in your site or simulate that dialog box.

Answer (score -1):

You can only set `Paper` size

```css
@media print {
    @page {
        size: A1 | A4 | A5 | landscape;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }

    body {
        padding: 75px;
    }
}
```

For more information: [See this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336995/set-printing-preferences-from-js)

**Notice: You cant change system default setting**

But,
You can try to use `react-pdf`