# Enforce specific printing settings with javascript irrespective of the default settings of the user's printer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a JavaScript function to print some contents. The function that I am using does the job correctly. The header, the footer and the title are set from the code. But I noticed that they are not being displayed in the preview. Also there are no margins left on all the four sides of the paper. Later when I checked the problem was associated with the default settings of the printer. I realised the paper was set to Letter and the header and footer was unchecked. So I had to manually do the settings to get the desired results.

So, I want to know is there a way to enforce the printing of the document the way I want even if the default of the user's printer is set to anything.

The below images show what I was getting and how I want to get it printed.

[image: This is how it prints at default settings(I do not want like this.)][image: This how I want to get it printed irrespective of the user's default printer settings.]

**Js function**

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.printContent = function() {
      var target = $(this);
      var title;
      if (target.attr("title") != undefined) {
        title = target.attr("title");
      } else {
        title = "Element Content"
      }
      var uid = Date.now();
      var printFrame = $("<iframe>", {
        id: "printFrame_" + uid,
        name: "printFrame_" + uid
      }).css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "-1000000px"
      }).appendTo($("body"));
      var frameHTML = $("<html>");
      $("<head>").appendTo(frameHTML);
      $("<title>").html(title).appendTo($("head", frameHTML));
      $("<body>").appendTo(frameHTML);
      if ($("body > link").length == 1) {
        $("body > link").clone().appendTo($("body", frameHTML));
      }
      $("body", frameHTML).append(target.html());
      var winFrame = window.frames['printFrame_' + uid];
      winFrame.document.open();
      winFrame.document.write(frameHTML.prop("outerHTML"));
      winFrame.document.close();
      setTimeout(function() {
        printFrame.focus();
        winFrame.print();
        printFrame.remove();
      }, 100);
    };
  
    $("#btnPrint").click(function() {
      $("#content").printContent();
    });
  });
```

Please suggest me how can I modify the above function to enforce the settings shown in the second image, like the paper size, margins, header and footer etc. from the function itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Printing Preferences from JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336995/set-printing-preferences-from-js)

Comment: No, Sir.  This is not solving my problem.

Comment: As noted in [the help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), "If you see a question and do not agree that it truly is a duplicate, **edit it to highlight the differences**..." In this case, show where you've put the CSS that is suggested in the duplicate.

Comment: Why do you think that `@page` does not work in your case. Seems to work perfectly fine to set the default margins that are used for printing.

Comment: @t.niese actually this function is printing the contents of a specific dov with all the css stylings suggest by one of the stack user. This function is doing exactly what I want except for this what i have mentioned in question.

Comment: Ok, but adding a css rule with `@page` to your workflow should work (would allow you to change the default margins applied). So why do you say that this won't solve your problem?

Comment: @t.niese Sorry, Sir my bad I completely missed that. I am going through the documentation now. Thank you.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am sorry I did not get what are you saying. But i shall try to rectify by lookig at it

Comment: Note from the article that was linked to, *So... after all day of looking, I think that I found the answer to my own question. In short, the answer is that JS and/or CSS will not allow you to override the default page setup of the client's browser.*

Comment: @Twisty Yes, Sir, I tried to search a lot and finally came to the same conclusion. Sorry to bother you in the last question comments.